# Problems sending measurement values via REST API

Tags: python, floating-point, iot, sensors

I'm trying to send data to an IoT cloud using some REST API in a python script.

Unfortunately, I encounter the following problem:

- sending fixed values to the cloud is working

  body='{ "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "99.0"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }'
- sending sensor values fails

  body='{ "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["' + str(temp) + '", "' + str(light) + '"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }'

both bodies look similar when using print(body), see below

- with fixed values

  { "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "99.0"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }
- with sensor values

  { "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "62.72"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }

Does anyone have some idea, how this could be solved.
Obviously, I need the sensor values, not the fixed one.

**additional comments after implementing the hints from Joseph**

This code is working fine ==> return code 202

```
body='{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"SENSOR_001\", \"measures\": [[\"24.0\", \"99.0\"]], \"sensorAlternateId\": \"4711_CR_SENS\" }'
        print (body)

    r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers, cert=('./credentials_0211.crt', './credentials_0211.key'))
```

body contains

```
{ "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "99.0"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }
```

Problem with above is the usage of fixed numbers for the measures, I need the one from the sensor.

following options are not working, those options would contain measures from a sensor, which is the real use case

**Option 1 ==> error 400**

```
measures = [temp, light]
    body = {
            "capabilityAlternateId" : capability,
            "measures" : [measures],
            "sensorAlternateId" : sensor
        }
    json_body = json.dumps(body)

#body contains

{'capabilityAlternateId': 'SENSOR_001', 'measures': [['24,0', '99,0']], 'sensorAlternateId': '4711_CR_SENS'}
```

**Option 2 ==> error 400**

```
body='{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"SENSOR_001\", \"measures\": [[\"' + str(temp) + '\", \"' + str(light) + '\"]], \"sensorAlternateId\": \"4711_CR_SENS\" }'
r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers, cert=('./credentials_0211.crt', './credentials_0211.key'))

#body contains

{ "capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "19.16"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS" }
```

Thanks a lot and best regards,
HyproN

Comment: It's not totally clear what the question is here. In what way is this failing? Does the Rest API return an error?

Generally speaking, rather than concatenating an existing string together, I'd recommend using a dictionary here, then encoding it (with `json.dumps()`). It will be much more flexible and less prone to errors.

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, I receive an error 400 for the version with concatenating.

Comment: How can I create a dictionary?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, 2 mins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating strings like this is quite error prone.

I'd recommend first populating a Python dictionary, then encoding it as a JSON string using the `json` module. In your case, it could look like this:

```
import json

capability_alternate_id = "SENSOR_001"
sensor_alternate_id = "4711_CR_SENS"
measures = ["24.0", "99.0"]

body = {
        "capabilityAlternateId": capability_alternate_id,
        "measures": [measures],
        "sensorAlternateId": sensor_alternate_id
    }

json_body = json.dumps(body)
```

Here, we set Python variables for `capability_alternate_id` (a string), `sensor_alternate_id` (a string), and `measures` (an array of strings). We then define a dictionary (called body), and define keys and values in line with the format defined in your post above.

`json.dumps(body)` takes the Python object `body`, and converts it into JSON (using a process called serialisation).

This is preferred to editing a string directly -- if you mess up defining body here, Python will throw an error that you can debug. When you manually concatenate a string together, Python will treat it like any other string, so it's difficult to debug errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph. This is really helpful and I get the dictionary part working.
I assume I handover the JSON to the request using data=jason_body in the request post call. Is this correct?
I tried and the first result was still 400 error, but I assume I made some mistake.

Comment: `data=json_body` is probably correct, but it depends how you're making the request, and also depends on the REST API you're communicating with.

Are you using the `requests` module and `requests.post`? If so, you may be able to pass the dictionary directly, with `requests.post(url, json=body)` (requests will encode the dictionary for you).

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include the code you're using to send your request, including an example where it works, and an example where it doesn't?

Comment: I did enter this information. Please let me know, if ypu need more input Joseph

Comment: Thanks HyproN.

Couple of things -- firstly, are you sure you're printing `json_body` in option #1? It looks to be using single quotes rather than double, as if you're printing `body` instead of the `dumps`'d version.

Secondly, there are commas in your measurements rather than decimal points. Can you double check this?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I corrected the comma, now the json variant is also working for the fixed values.

However, the values foom the sensor are still failing. I cannot send them via json and also not via concatinating. I don't see any difference. Do you see something?

{"capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["23.6", "29.3"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS"}

Comment: Thanks for checking. I corrected the comma, now the json variant is also working for the fixed values.

However, the values foom the sensor are still failing. I cannot send them via json and also not via concatinating. I don't see any difference. Do you see something?

this is not working==>

{"capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["23.6", "29.3"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS"}

this is working==>

{"capabilityAlternateId": "SENSOR_001", "measures": [["24.0", "99.0"]], "sensorAlternateId": "4711_CR_SENS"}

Comment: Very strange. Syntactically, it seems valid to me. Is it possible that your REST API is rejecting values that fall outside a fixed range?

Comment: OK, I figured out what the renaining issue was. there was typ e conflict between the sensor and the cloud.
after aligning this, the sensor values are taken over.

thank sagain Joseph for your help!